# que es estructura lógica en lenguajes de programación?

Tags: javascript, php, css, visual-studio, wampserver

que es estructura lógica en lenguajes de programación ? busqué en google y no lo encontré

```
int ledPin = 13;        // LED que se encuentra en el pin 13
   void setup(){ 
   pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // El p1n 13 será una salida digital 
} 
void loop(){ 
   digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);  // Enciende el LED
   delay(1000);                 // Pausa de 1 segundo 
   digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);   // Apaga el LED
```

Comment: La estructura lógica en un lenguaje de programación se refiere a la forma en que se organiza y escribe el código de un programa. Esto incluye la estructuración del código en diferentes bloques y la forma en que se utilizan las diferentes estructuras de control de flujo, como condiciones y bucles, para controlar el flujo de ejecución del programa. Una buena estructura lógica es importante para escribir código que sea fácil de entender y mantener. PD: que onda con tu codigo?

Comment: @RuslanLópez, OP puso muchas etiquetas, pero se le olvidó incluir arduino.

Comment: y que significa estructura lógica cuando se dice que alguna de ellas son: bloques if, switch, case ?